# multiple screen scroll in android as iphone platform

Tags: android

Please help me for scroll multiple screen as in iphone platform. I want to scroll horizontal the screen in android, how can I manage and what is saying for this feature.

Comment: You should take a look at `ViewPager` in the Android Compatibility Library.. see this link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

You can also take a look at this post on the android developer blog - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the following link
https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager
you will get the what you are required.